# Can SharePoint be used as an LMS for organization?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I create online courses for our large organization using Adobe Captivate. Our organization has started using SharePoint 2013 last year. Can SharePoint 2013 be used an an LMS (Learning Management System) for our e Learning courses?

Answer (score 1):

Not well. Sharepoint could technically be configured to track learning records, host videos, etc.  But it wouldn't do a lot of it very well, and it would require a significant investment of time and a lot of custom development to get pieces interacting half as well as a 'real' LMS.

There's a reason LMS systems are expensive - they are also complex.

Answer (score 0):

There are several 3rd party implementations out there that allow you to use SP as a base for a LMS. Implementing it yourself will most likely cost you more than these finished products will charge.

Comment: Could you name some of them?

Comment: I try not to name 3rd party products, esp since I have not used any to a degree where I would feel confident to recommend them. I would make sure a solution will be able to handle SCORM content, since that's the normal format. For moss I would point in the direction of the SP-Learning kit but only to look at it 1st.